# website seems to shrink on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I've been playing around with a website for a while now, and it seems like when I pull it up on chrome, on a mobile, it completely breaks.

In order to bug fix this, I made a minimal copy of my nav bar, and the issue still happens.

I've got the code below, if anyone could help me, that'd be great :).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <!-- Heading -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
  
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
   <!-- Navbar toggle button -->
   <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" 
   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
   aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
   aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <!-- Navbar logo -->
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="/#">
    <img class="img img-responsive" style="width:48px; height:48px;" alt="logo"
         src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png" />
   </a>

   <!-- Some other navbar shit; mostly  -->
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto animated ">
     <li class="nav-item" id="home-navi">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home </a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item" id="help-navi" >
      <a class="nav-link" id="help" href="/#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Help </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
        </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's photos of what's going wrong. (Both tested on the developer tools Samsung Galaxy S5).

[on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMJ5z.png)

[on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEZP9.png)

-Thanks, Sam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it!

Turns out, it was a problem with the meta tag.

Adding this as the meta tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

Seems to fix it on chrome.

-Hope this helps, Sam.